# Pop Out Text Box in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, messagebox

I've created a report in SSRS where there are several textboxes in a summary row that have more than 15 characters.  These are notes type columns that they do not want to display all the information so we've truncated the values so that the rows are all the same size and do not expand.  I've added a Tooltip to view the entire information.  However, they would like to have an action that pops-out the full text if possible when the field is clicked.  Is this possible, without making a drillthrough or drilldown report?  It would just be a click on the field Text Box pops out a window of some sort to show more information.  I know SSRS isn't built to do this but wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty crude but you could set an action on the text box. Select Go to URL and then set the expression to something like

```
="javascript:( alert('" + Fields!MyNoteColumn.Value + "') )"
```

This will display a message box with the column contents without leaving the page etc..

Comment: It's not Pretty!  But I actually like it.  Thank you for sending me the proper expression before it was not working as expected.